# When to use request in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am reading an article casting `created_at` to a string as it will return as an object by default. When to make request exactly? I know that the request can be used to transform one format to another. But when exactly? Any rules like when you create a data column you must use it? Things like that?

Comment: pls, be precise with your question.

Comment: Please add some more context.  You talk about a request and then the created_at attribute... what did you need help with?

Comment: Hello Jassica, please provide a complete question. In order to make it check this guide: [ask]

Comment: please add some more details, what exactly you want to do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `created_at` as a string is not a best practice. Laravel Eloquent will automatically extract them from DB and cast them to [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) instance, so you can transform it with a string (with `->format()`) whenever you want.

Plus, having a Carbon object, you have access to lots of methods to handle your date, like comparison, extraction of single data (like day, month, hours...), so it doesn't make sense to cast it to a string, imho.